# eyed3 add tag release date resolves in error "can't assign to operator"

Tags: python, mp3, eyed3

I try to add the release-date tag to an mp3 file using eyed3 in python. 
It works fine for the tags "artist" and "date". It is not working for "release-date":

```
`audiofile.tag.release-date = dateToTag`
```

throws the error:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

This is my setup:

```
`audiofile = eyed3.load(os.path.join("../mockDirectory", file))
 audiofile.initTag()
 audiofile.tag.artist = u"Artist"
 audiofile.tag.year  = year
 audiofile.tag.release-date = dateToTag`
```

The value of *dateToTag* is *2017-10-27*, formatted according to the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/eyed3/latest/eyed3.pdf) page 30: yyyy-mm-dd. 
Why is the date format throwing a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the syntax error because '-' isn't allowed in python identifiers. Python parses is as an operation "audiofile.tag.release (minus) date".

Try to replace - with an underscore like:

`audiofile.tag.release_date = dateToTag`

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: I know this post is like 3 yrs old but how do you know what commands work and which don't? (The documentation has little about the actual python library). Thank you!